# After Parsing timestamp contains timezone to Date object, does Date object contain timezone information

Tags: java, date, datetime

If we have timestamps that contain the timezone info, like 2017-07-03T17:30:00-04:00, and parse it into java.Date or joda.DateTime.

Does it contains timezone information ?
I am asking this because i want to compare two different date instance. So if it does not contain timezone information, the day difference will be wrong with different timezones

UPDATE:
I run a quick unit test to verify, first convert date instance to milliseconds and convert back to TimeUnit after subtract these two milliseconds. The hours are different for different timezone

Comment: What does the javadoc of those two classes say?

Comment: I think that should based on the way to calculate the day difference, first convert it to milliseconds, and compare these two dates with milliseconds. However, i run a quick unit test, it gives me different hours with different timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `java.util.Date` and Joda-Time have been supplanted by the java.time classes.

Your input string `2017-07-03T17:30:00-04:00` is in standard ISO 8601 format and has an offset-from-UTC at the end. That `-04:00` means the string represents a moment four hours behind UTC.

This offset is not a time zone. A time zone is a history of offsets for a particular region. For example, `America/Barbados` or `America/New_York`.

Parse your string as an `java.time.OffsetDateTime` object.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-07-03T17:30:00-04:00" );
```

> odt.toString(): 2017-07-03T17:30:00-04:00

You may compare `OffsetDateTime` instances by calling the methods `IsEqual`, `isBefore`, and `isAfter`.

To see the same simultaneous moment in UTC, extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2017-07-03T21:30:00Z

The `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu` and means UTC.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to depend on what type of `DateTime` you use, as of Java 8 you have these options:

- A `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime`. It is going to discard time zone information, you will wind up with a value that is 'valid' only for the local timezone. This value is ambiguous without some context as to the specific timezone of the server process which generated the value.
- A `ZonedDate` or `ZonedDateTime`. This one preserves the time zone. Comparison is still going to be ambiguous: you have issues like DST or calendaring changes to contend with (depending on the range of datetime which you need to be compatible with). For sorting/comparison purposes you would probably want to convert it to a reference timescale, which is why:
- An `Instant` represents a particular moment in time, on the absolute timescale of UTC. Any `Instant` is directly comparable with any other `Instant` and any ambiguity in values is resolved by the definition of `Instant`. Input values will be converted to the matching counterparts in UTC, so the original timezone (if any) will be lost even if the absolute time value will be preserved correctly. `Instant` is therefore not a good choice if you rely on the timezone to make decisions about location or locale, for instance.